# Calcular o produto de uma operação entre dois dataframes condicionalmente

Tags: r

Suponhamos que eu tenha esse dois dataframes:

```
set.seed(123)
df1<-data.frame(rep=rep(1:4,each=360),parc=rep(1:40,each=36),trat=rep(sample(1:10),each=36),tree=rep(1:36,40),med=1,dap_prev=rnorm(1440, mean = 12))
df2<-data.frame(med=rep(1:18,each=10),trat=rep(sample(1:10)),b0=rnorm(180),b1=rnorm(180))
```

Em `df2` preciso recuperar os valores de `df2$b0` e `df2$b1` que correspondam aos critérios `df1$med == df2$med` e `df1$trat == df2$trat`. Em seguida criar uma nova coluna em `df1` cujo produto é `df2$b0 + df2$b1 * df1$dap_prev`.

Tentei com esse comando abaixo, mas claro que não funcionou:

```
df1$ddap_cm <- df2$b0[df2$med == df1$med & df2$trat == df1$trat] + df2$b1[df1$med == df2$med & df1$trat == df2$trat] * df1$dap_prev
```

Toda ajuda é bem vinda. Grato.

EDIT:

Acabei encontrando uma solução bem simples com dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- left_join(df1, df2, by = c("med", "trat")) # copia as colunas df2$b0 e df2$b1 que cumpram os critérios
df1$ddap_cm <- df1$b0 + (df1$b1*df1$dap_prev)
```

Comment: No comando que você fez há um erro de digitação `df.1$trat` quando acredito que vc queria dizer `df1$trat`. Teste e veja se atende ao pedido!

Comment: Como disse o Flavio, acho que o problema só estava no erro de digitação mesmo

Comment: Como é que `df1$dap_prev` não é indexado pelas condições lógicas?

Answer (score 1):

Uma proposta usando o R básico. Fiz uma alteração nos Dfs para simular casos mais reais onde tem dados que não estão nos dois Dfs

```
set.seed(123)
df1<-data.frame(rep=rep(1:4,each=360),parc=rep(1:40,each=36),trat=rep(sample(1:10),each=36),tree=rep(1:36,40),med=c(rep(1,1000),rep(4,400),rep(20,40)),dap_prev=rnorm(1440, mean = 12))
df2<-data.frame(med=rep(1:18,each=10),trat=rep(sample(1:15,10)),b0=rnorm(180),b1=rnorm(180))

df2$inddf1med=0
for (i in unique(df1$med))df2$inddf1med[df2$med==i]=1
df2$inddf1trat=0
for (i in unique(df1$trat))df2$inddf1trat[df2$trat==i]=1
sel=df2[df2$inddf1med == 1 & df2$inddf1trat==1,]

df1$res=NA
for (i in 1:nrow(sel)){
  selc=df1$med==sel$med[i]&df1$trat==sel$trat[i]
df1$res[selc]=sel$b0[i] + sel$b1[i] * df1$dap_prev[selc]
}
df1f=df1[!is.na(df1$res),]
```

Answer (score 1):

Tem que primeiro criar a nova coluna, só depois pode atribuir os respetivos valores do cálculo.

```
i1 <- df1$med == df2$med
i2 <- df1$trat == df2$trat

df1$ddap_cm <- NA
df1$ddap_cm <- df2$b0[i1 & i2] + df2$b1[i1 & i2] * df1$dap_prev[i1 & i2]
```

**Nota:** Se houver valores `NA` nas tabelas originais, deve usar `which(i1 & i2)` para indexar as colunas de interesse.

Comment: `df1$dap_prev` não leva em consideração os critérios `i1` e `i2`, como está no seu código

Comment: @RafaelCunha Eu reparei mas tem que levar. Se não como é, recicla? Os vetores têm de ter o mesmo comprimento. Se calhar é melhor perguntar isso ao OP.

Comment: eu só comentei de acordo com o tópico, nem parei pra pensar se deve entrar em consideração ou não

Comment: Acabei construindo um solução mais simples com dplyr mas que teve o mesmo efeito. Obrigado.

Comment: @AníbalDeboniNeto você tem que entender certinho o que você precisa e como vai fazer. Se tiver sido um erro de digitação, como foi apontado anteriormente, o `summary` da sua nova variável tem uns certos valores, que diferem caso você considere os critérios `i1` e `i2` levantados pelo Rui. E o `summary` é também diferente com essa abordagem utilizando o pacote `dplyr`

Comment: @RafaelCunha no código que eu colei aqui aquele ponto era um erro de digitação, no meu script não tinha aquele ponto no nome da variável. O merge() associou corretamente os valores de b0 e b1 para cada observação. Obrigado.